# Error on Telerik RadScheduler

Tags: telerik

I´m new to the Telerik RadScheduler. I've already saw the example on [Telerik site](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/outlook2007/defaultcs.aspx). But keep receiving this message: ***"~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config"***.

Can anyone point me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the entry for the HttpHandler in your web.config. They usually put the xml to add to your web.config in the error message so you can manually add it.

Another option to add it is, go into design view, you should be able to right click the control and select an option to register the web.config entries.

Also, check out [this link at Telerik's site](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/troubleshooting.html) for some general troubleshooting related to web.config entries.

If all else fails, try posting your issue on [Telerik's RadScheduler forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/scheduler.aspx), they usually answer pretty quickly.